# Change page background color based on active Bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use jQuery to change the **page background color** based on which Bootstrap tab is active.

This is the only script used by Bootstrap tabs:

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

I need to modify the body's `background-color` CSS property depending on which tab is active.

The fiddle below has bare-bones Bootstrap 3 tabs with a gold background color. I need to be able to set a seperate hex value for each of the four tabs.

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c4ohLmjx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the contains selector `*` to add the click event and check for a particular `id` to set the page `background` color based on which Bootstrap tab you click :

```
$('[id*="tab-"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')

    if(this.id=="tab-1"){
        $('body').css('background', 'red');
    }
    else if(this.id=="tab-2"){
        $('body').css('background', 'green');
    }
    else if(this.id=="tab-3"){
        $('body').css('background', 'blue');
    }
    else if(this.id=="tab-4"){
        $('body').css('background', 'purple');
    }
});
```

[Here a working jsfiddle to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/xdadkgjk/)

Comment: @user3236756 I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out;

[Color Change Based On Hover](http://codepen.io/ianfarb/pen/DegqJ)

This is currently set on `:hover`, if you're looking forward to keep the colors on the background, utilize `:active` and apply the specific color to the `background` property

Answer (score 0):

Put this code. You may change the color hex to your own.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#one')
        $('body').css('background-color', 'gold'); //gold
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#two')
        $('body').css('background-color', '#ff0000'); //red
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#three')
        $('body').css('background-color', '#2980b9'); //blue
    if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#four')
        $('body').css('background-color', '#8e44ad'); //purple
})
```

**Working Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/c4ohLmjx/2/